# Copy remote database views to local database as tables

Tags: mysql, sql-server, linux, database

I currently have access to **only the views** on a remote database, and I'm trying to copy the data of those views locally so that I can work faster. I've tried to use `mysqldump` to create a `.sql` file and load that, but it doesn't seem to work.

To get the remote db:

`$ mysqldump --single-transaction -u username -p -h somesite.com -P 32000 db_name > mysql.sql`

To copy to local:

`$ mysql -u root -p mydatabase < mysql.sql`

But I get an error

`ERROR 1146 (42S02) at line 668: Table 'db_name.some_view' doesn't exist`

My local database is completely empty except me creating an empty one using the command `create database mydatabase;` in the mysql shell.

Am I getting this problem because I can't use this method in the first place since I only have access to the views in the remote database?

Comment: Probably because you don't have the SHOW CREATE VIEW priviledge which is required for this to work

Comment: Is there a way for me to use a command to find out if I have that privilege?

Answer (score 0):

Did you taken the data from the remote system correctly.If not try this command once you connect through remotely to database server,the command is

- mysqldump -u username -h 192.168.X.X -P password --routines>xxxx.sql

It will ask the password of the database.Till now data is only in database server.From your local system use this command to take the data from database server,the command is

- rsync -vaH username@192.168.X.X:/datalocation /yourlocation

Now the data is on your local system.Then after create one database in your system.

- mysql
- create database;
- grant all privileges on databasename .*to databaseschema@'%' identified by 'password';
- flush privileges;

I think this may help you,if not sorry bro.